# Sort list of tuples based on second element while alternating over third element

Tags: algorithm, scala, sorting, functional-programming, tuples

Given a list of tuples:

```
val mylist = List(('orange', 0.9, 10), ('apple', 0.8, 10), ('mellon', 0.7, 10), 
                  ('car', 0.5, 2), ('truck', 0.5, 2),('tablet', 0.3, 3))
```

I would like to sort them in descending order with respect to the second element of the tuple. However, I would like to pick them by category, one at a time (third element) alternatively. The output should be the following list:

```
('orange', 0.9, 10)
('car', 0.5, 2)
('tablet', 0.3, 3)
('apple', 0.8, 10) 
('truck', 0.5, 2)
('mellon', 0.7, 10)
```

What would be the functional way of doing it in Scala?

PS: Notice that the the result must reflect the ordering of the third element, that is, 10 appears before 2, and 2 before 3.

Comment: any particular reason why 'car' is at 2nd position and not 'truck' ?

Comment: no reason. if the second element is equal, there is no preference

Comment: one brute force would be sort the list according to categories first. Then create n sublists for n categories and store the like items in it. Then sort the sublists according to second element. Then add all the elements back into list taking 1 from each category.

Comment: for alternative part if the categories are 10, 9, 8, 7, 6 then would the desired output be 10, 8, 9, 6, 7 ? If yes, just ignore 1st category swap rest with each other swap(i, i+1) types.

Comment: yes, the desired output is precisely that, when possible. when the elements run out that's fine, keep the order of the remaining groups. it'd be great if you could share the swapping thing. I was looking for something functional oriented, but if not possible it's ok with me .

Comment: i am not familiar with scala code but in english it would be like this. Your storage of categories would something like a list of list (i.e. list of categories which is list of items). Then you can swap the the outer lists and merge back the items from inner lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by adding two indices to each item in the list:

- The item's **category position** among all existing categories (i.e. 0 for category 10, 1 for 2 and 2 for 3)
- The item's **index within its category** by descending value of the second tuple element

Once these are added, you can order by them both (with the index withn the category taking precedence)

```
// traverse once to get a map of Category -> CategoryIndex
val categoryOrder: Map[Int, Int] = mylist.map(_._3).distinct.zipWithIndex.toMap

val result: List[(String, Double, Int)] = mylist
  .groupBy(_._3).mapValues(_.sortBy(-_._2).zipWithIndex) // add the index of each item within its category
  .toList.flatMap(_._2) // remove group keys and flatMap to get back to tuples
  .sortBy { case (t, indx) => (indx, categoryOrder(t._3)) } // order by index in category and category index
  .map(_._1) // remove indices

println(result)
// List((orange,0.9,10), (car,0.5,2), (tablet,0.3,3), (apple,0.8,10), (truck,0.5,2), (mellon,0.7,10))
```